# Can ReactiveMongo can be used in Lagom framework?

Tags: mongodb, playframework-2.6, lagom

I need to convert a existing Play + Scala + Mongodb application into Lagom micro services. But all the examples I have tested were using Cassadra.

There is Read Support for mongodb, as mentioned in their documentation.
[There is plugin too](https://github.com/scullxbones/akka-persistence-mongo).

This means, can we not write into mongodb collections?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you notionally can create a MongoDB persistence API. You'll need to implement:

```
com.lightbend.lagom.scaladsl.persistence.{ 
    PersistenceComponents, 
    PersistentEntityRegistry, 
    ReadSidePersistenceComponents,
    WriteSidePersistenceComponents 
}
```

and `play.api.db.DBComponents`.

You can see an example implementation [here](https://github.com/lagom/lagom/tree/master/persistence-jdbc) for JDBC.